# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'employeename')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

add-employee.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <h3> Create Employee </h3>
    <form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class ="form-control" id = "employeename"
                [(ngModel)] = "employee.employeename" name = "employeename">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age</label>
            <input  class ="form-control" id = "age"
                [(ngModel)] = "employee.age" name = "age">
        </div>

        <button class = "btn btn-success" type ="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

add-employee.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { EmployeeserviceService } from '../employeeservice.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-employee',
  templateUrl: './add-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-employee.component.css']
})
export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employee !: Employee;

  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.employee);

    this.employeeService.saveEmployee(this.employee).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

}
```

I am new to Angular and I am trying to create a sample employee CRUD application for hands-on experience. But while creating POST API creation I am getting:

> cannot read property employeename

I don't know where I done a mistake can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your code, you didn't initialize value (instance) for `employee`. Add this line in `ngOnInit()` method: `this.employee = new Employee(0, "", 0);`

Comment: @YongShun Is there is any other way to solve this issue because I don't want to show the zero value in the input field.

Comment: Consider making `age` property as nullable. `age : number  | null` And initialize the `age` with `null`. This will not show zero as initial value in the text box, however you may require to write the field validation for age to make sure that user has filled `age` if `age` is a required field.

Comment: Hi @YongShun could please give me a small code snippet to make the variable null. I was totally confused on how to make the age to null.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem as mentioned in the comment that you miss out to initialize the `Employee` instance to `employee` variable before using it. Initialize the instance to `employee` variable would fix the issue.

```js
export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employee = new Employee(0, "", 0);
  }

  ...

}
```

---

For hiding the initialize age value (`0`), you may consider applying `age` property in `Employee` class as nullable.

```js
export class Employee {
    id: number;
    employeename: string;
    age: number | null;

    constructor(id: number, employeename: string, age: number | null){
        this.id=id;
        this.employeename=employeename;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

And initialize `age` as `null`.

```js
export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

 ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employee = new Employee(0, "", null);
  }

  ...
}
```